# Executar scripts na rota quando acessada direto

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Bom eu to com um probleminha que quando alguém acessa http://www.meulink.com/rota
sem ter aberto direto no index (http://www.meulink.com/) e navegado pelo menu, os scripts contidos no arquivo de rotas, especificamente dentro da função:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    meus scripts
});
```

Routes

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import HomePage from '@/pages/Home'
import SecondPage from '@/pages/Secundaria'
import ThirdPage from '@/pages/Terciaria'
import FourthPage from '@/pages/Quartenaria'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: HomePage
    },
    {
        name: 'Secundaria',
        path: '/secundaria',
        component: SecondPage,
        props: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Terciaria',
        path: '/terciaria',
        component: ThirdPage,
        props: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Quartenaria',
        path: '/quartenaria',
        component: FourthPage,
        props: true
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {

    var globalNav = $('[data-globalnav]'),
        // Link dentro do menu global cujo href é igual à rota de destino
        link = globalNav.find(`a[href="${to.path}"]`);

    // Define como item atual o 'li' que contém o link encontrado
    globalNav.meGlobalnav().setCurrent(link.parent());

})

export default router
```

não executam. Como eu faço pra contornar isso?

Comment: Podes mostrar  a tua array `routes`?

Comment: Adicionei à postagem